# Open with stopped working on Android 9, how to fix?

Tags: android

I develop a music player which I want to open in a file manager. I added the following intent-filter in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.app.MusicPlayer"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.01" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/flac" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-flac" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
        </intent-filter>            
    </activity>
</application>
```

It worked great until version 9, and after only Google player is shown, what I need to change to return my player in the list?

Comment: `<data android:scheme="file" />` You probably will get no file scheme but a content scheme. So add that scheme but maybe better remove that line.

Comment: Further: sometimes a separate intent-filter for every mimeType can do the trick. Try one mimeType first.